# JPA how to join these entities

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Given the JPA entities below, I want to get **all Debits which has a Request with at least one succesful status.**

There can be many requests with the same debit_id and different statuses

Should I use something like this or there is a better way of doing things

*entityManager.createQuery( "select c from Debit d join d.id where request.status =Succesful"*

```
@Entity(name = "T_DEBIT")
public class Debit {
  public enum Status { NEW, OLD } 

  @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false, length = 20)
  @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
  private Status status;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Account account;

}
```

and other entity is

```
@Entity(name = "T_REQUEST")
public class Request{  

  public enum Status { PENDING, FAILED, SUCCESFUL}  

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "DEBIT_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Debit debit;

  @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false, length = 20)
  @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
  private Status status;

 }
```

Please do comment if anything is missing instead of closing or downvoting the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically:

```
select d
from T_DEBIT d
where exists (
    select r
    from T_REQUEST r
    where 
    r.debit.id = d.id and
    r.status = SUCCESSFUL
)
```

Check for enum syntax inside JPQL, I do not usually use enums for entities and it could be wrong in this example.

As a style issue, i would make entity name == class name instead of entity name == table name. It makes the fact that JPQL **IS NOT** SQL clearer

**UPDATE**

Spring asks for a solution to a similar problem. The way to work these things out is very systematic:

a) Rewrite your problem, using only basic filters and the following expressions:

1. "exists some ... such that condition is true"
2. "for all ... condition is true"

b) Translate:

1. This case becomes `exists (select ... where condition)`
2. This case becomes `not exists (select ... where NOT condition)`

In Spring's particular question, "exclude all succesfull requests", the goal is not very clear. If he/she means "get all debits without successful requests", then you would do:

a) Rewrite the question as "get all debits such that *for all associated requests, request status is not SUCCESSFUL*".
b) Translate as

```
select d
from T_DEBIT d
where not exists (
    select r
    from T_REQUEST r
    where 
    -- This is the join condition, so it should not be negated
    r.debit.id = d.id and 
    -- This is the actual filtering condition, negate as this is a FOR ALL
    not (r.status != SUCCESSFUL)
)
```

Then you could simplify that last condition, getting:

```
select d
from T_DEBIT d
where not exists (
    select r
    from T_REQUEST r
    where 
    r.debit.id = d.id and
    r.status = SUCCESSFUL
)
```

Comment: thank you, could you explain why using "where" instead of a join here?

Comment: @spring The where clause is not required here because the EXISTS keyword has been used: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php

Comment: @Spring You use joins where you want to retrieve data from more than one table. When you just want to filter one table by the contents of another one, it is more correct not to join but use an existential filter (`exists`) in the `where` clause: it gives the DBMS the possibility to be more efficient and in many cases avoids the need to use `distinct` to filter out duplicate results

Comment: @Spring Even if I am writing about "tables", keep in mind that this query is a JPQL query and not a SQL query. JPQL is usually a thin layer above SQL, but there are differences.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse tnx but in that link all examples are with "WHERE EXISTS"? another thing is it says it is very inefficient, but it does not give a better option, what do you think?

Comment: @Spring It can be inefficient if you are using "toy" databases. Decent DBMS (eg: Oracle, PostgreSQL) should process it pretty much as if it were a join.

Comment: @gpeche tnx, one more thing, if I want to exclude all succesfull requests, what should i do? where not exixts?

Comment: @gpeche thank you could you check this, I discovered I also need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810103/sql-multiple-where-clause