# SQL multiple where clause

Tags: sql, jpa

I couldn't find if using multiple where clauses like this is valid or not(I use JPA, MySQL) I need multiple where clauses one of them will be a "not" here, or am I missing something?

```
select d from T_DEBIT d where d.status=PENDING and 
where not exists (
select r
from T_REQUEST r
where 
r.debit.id = d.id and
r.status = SUCCESSFUL
)
```

Please do ask if you need further information,

Comment: You have an extra `where` up there, before the `not exists` clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPA provides support for subqueries.  [See the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_subqueries)

> Subqueries may be used in the WHERE or HAVING clause. The syntax for
>   subqueries is as follows:
>
> ```
> subquery ::= simple_select_clause subquery_from_clause [where_clause
> [groupby_clause] [having_clause]
> ```
>
> Subqueries are restricted to the WHERE and HAVING clauses in this
>   release. Support for subqueries in the FROM clause will be considered
>   in a later release of the specification.

Your query appears to be written in SQL, converting it to JPQL will require a few things:

1. Use the entity names instead of tables names.
2. If `status` is a field of type `String` be sure to enclose the statuses such as `PENDING` with single quotes.
3. [Follow syntax for the exists expression](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_exists)

I believe you could also write your query as a join (PSEUDO CODE):

```
select d 
from T_DEBIT d 
left join T_REQUEST tr
on d.id = tr.debit_id
where d.status = 'PENDING'
and tr.status = 'SUCCESSFUL`
and tr.debit_id is null
```

Comment: maybe something like this:"select d from T_DEBIT d where d.status=PENDING and not exists (select..)" so only one where clause dont wanna use join

Comment: The subquery you have should work fine, if you take the join approach take a look at this:  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html  I believe you want the fourth diagram down.

Comment: ok my entitis are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808695/jpa-how-to-join-these-entities and what I want is "all debits with a status of "NEW" AND there should NOT be any succesful requests related to these debit ids"

Answer (score 4):

This is not valid sql:

```
select d from T_DEBIT d 
where d.status=PENDING 
and where not exists (subquery)
```

The problem is that the word where appears twice in the main query.  Simply remove it so your query becomes:

```
select d from T_DEBIT d 
where d.status=PENDING 
and not exists (subquery)
```

The other answers also make valid points.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple constraints in the `WHERE` is fine, as are subqueries, but you probably want the value you're comparing `r.status` with wrapped in quotes if using literal strings. Unless *we're* missing something.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the purpose of this subquery? Would it no be a lot easier to simply include it in the main query?

```
 select d from T_DEBIT d, T_REQUEST r where d.status='PENDING' and r.status != 'SUCCESSFUL' and r.debit.id= d.id
```

Comment: Your version might return duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

For multiple *WHERE* clauses use *AND* like:

```
    SELECT column1, column2, columnN 
    FROM table_name
    WHERE [condition1] AND [condition2] AND [condition3];
```

For more info on AND & OR: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-and-or-clauses.htm